# Best approach to design image uploading with scale?

Tags: android, laravel, design-patterns, upload, azure-storage

I am building an app which allows users to create posts like twitter. Each post can have upto 10 images attached. I need to store all images in its original size in Azure blob storage but also require 2 smaller size (thumbnail) versions to display previews in the app.

My backend is Laravel (PHP) and the app is android. I have some idea on how to do this but I struggling between many pros and cons of each approach. I am asking this here to know any tried and tested implementation.

Some constraints:

- Post should only be created after all images are uploaded and thumbnail URL links are generated.
- User should not have to stay in the app while image uploading/processing is in progress. Idea is to minimize user impact.
- All images are to be stored in Azure blob storage. Backend service can be used temporarily for the purpose but files cannot be stored in these servers for long.
- Only the owner of the post is allowed to create the image blobs. But the images can be read by public. This is anyway a functionality of Azure storage and doesn't require any custom work.

Some additional questions:

- Where is the best places to process images to thumbnails - app or server ?
- How does Whatsapp/Facebook/Twitter achieve this in their design ?

Let me know if you need any additional details for a better design approach. Please feel free to throw any idea or share any source where I can read up on something similar.

Answer (score 0):

- For uploading images,

When creating post, you can save the post in database and using a sync mechanism like workmanager to upload the images first and then the post data. Workmanager will handle the syncing process in the background.

- For thumbnails,

As the post is created after all the images are uploaded, the server should create the thumbnails and save the links when requested by the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a webjob function to read the original image, create the thumbnails and store them in blob storage.

The webjob will be triggered by a queue. So, when you add the original image in the blob you are going to add a message in a queue.

When the webjob finished with the resizing it can toggle a field in the database to make it public.

Since, you are storing the images in blob storage by default they will be readonly available for public.

The following is an old article but a good place to start:
https://ppolyzos.com/2016/03/22/azure-webjobs-to-resize-an-image-to-multiple-dimensions/

You may also use Azure functions:
http://jameschambers.com/2016/11/Resizing-Images-Using-Azure-Functions/

Another solution to almost achieve the same result is to use Event Grid:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event?tabs=dotnet